# Unable to Fire onItemCommand event

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, telerik-grid

I am unable to guess the issue here , as the event of grid item command is not executing .I also changes the pageevent validation state but of no use. 
I am pasting .aspx code as well as 
The grid is binded perfectly

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="frds" runat="server" OnItemCommand="go_frd" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
<MasterTableView>
<Columns>
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="bt" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("frd_ID") %>' Text="test" />
</ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
</Columns>
</MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

The event is this

```
   protected void go_frd(object o, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "frd_go")
    {
        Response.Redirect("Profiling.aspx?uid=" + e.CommandArgument);
    }
    if (e.CommandName == "add_frd")
    {
        db_accessDataContext db = new db_accessDataContext();
        Frd_request req = new Frd_request();

        db.AddFriend(Int64.Parse(cur_mem_id), Int64.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.addFriend", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"memID", Int64.Parse(cur_mem_id));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"frdID", Int64.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
}
```

I tried many approaches but unable to fire the event for button in grid 
I checked it by putting a break point as well ,the trouble is it don't even start execution of the event 
Binding COde

```
    string query = "my query containing the frd_id ,works fine in query builder and it also is shown grid view "; 
try { SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
 SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con); 
adapter.Fill(d0); con.Close(); 
} catch (Exception ex) { } 
frds.DataSource = d0; 
frds.DataBind();
```

Comment: I checked it by putting a break point as well ,the trouble is it don't even start execution of the event

Comment: How are you binding the grid?

Comment: string query = "my query containing the frd_id ,works fine in query builder and it also is shown grid view ";

        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            adapter.Fill(d0);
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        
        frds.DataSource = d0;
        frds.DataBind();

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the CommandName:

```
<asp:Button ID="bt" runat="server" 
     CommandName="frd_go" 
     CommandArgument='<%#Eval("frd_ID") %>' Text="test" />
```

Comment: I tried this as well , I checked it by putting a break point as well ,the trouble is it don't even start execution of the event

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue today. 
In my radgrid I had the code to build the sql and populate the radgrid in the page_load event, but I forgot to add

if (!IsPostBack) { }

around this code, so on every page load the grid was being rebuilt and the onitemcommand method was not working. The page seemed to be was posting back on button click or rowclick, but the event was just not firing. Try adding the if (!isPostback) code around your databinding and you might find it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set `EnablePostBackOnRowClick` property to `true` for `ClientSettings`. However this will cause a full post back.

```
.
.
.
</MasterTableView>
<ClientSettings EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true"> 
</ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

You may want to check this [thread on Telerik forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/style-builder/radgrid-not-firing-postback-on-itemcommand-events.aspx)

Comment: where are you doing the databinding to the radgrid. Do it under the _NeedDataSource event of the radgrid (so you don't have to worry about when to rebind the grid and so on). Have a look at http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-advanced-data-binding.html` In this case, make sure you only set the datasource. There is no need to call DataBind()